# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2+n+1}{(n+1)^2}=1$

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

So, here's the sequence $\{x_n\}$ defined by the following formula:

$$x_n = \frac{n^2+n+1}{(n+1)^2}$$

I want to try and prove this from the definition. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Then, we need an integer $N(\epsilon) > 0$ such that:

$$n > N \implies |x_n - 1| < \epsilon$$

$$|x_n-1| = |\frac{n^2+n+1}{(n+1)^2} - 1| = |\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}| < \frac{1}{n}$$

Then, define $N(\epsilon) = [\frac{1}{\epsilon}]+1$, where $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$. Since we have our required $N(\epsilon)$, this proves the desired result.

Does the proof above work? If it doesn't, why and how can I fix it?

Comment: $N(\epsilon)$ doesn't have to be be an integer.  It just needs to be a  real so that $n > N(\epsilon)$ where $n$ is natural will give result.   So you just need $\frac 1n \le \epsilon $ or $n \ge \frac 1\epsilon$. So set $N(\epsilon) = \frac 1\epsilon$. Much easier to express and to follow. And your proof and reasoning is perfect.

Comment: It's perfect.  Alternatively you can divide numerator and denominator by $n^2$ and apply limits to both of them justifying the steps.

Comment: Oh my book said that N has to be a positive integer but I've seen what you're talking about it with N being real. Thank you for verifying my proof!

Comment: Okay, we can't argue with the books.  SO say let $N$ be anysuch that $N > \frac 1{\epsilon}$ by archimedian principle  we know such exist.  If you want to define it you can use the ceiling function $\lceil \frac 1\epsilon \rceil$  or, as you put it $N = [\frac 1\epsilon] + 1$.... Okay... I'll admit it.  The more I read your argument the less reasonable my initial objection seems. ... But I think if you state "so we need an $N$ so that $n \ge N > \frac 1\epsilon$ then $|\frac n{(n+1)^2}|<\frac 1n < \epsilon$.  And $N$ may be any integer $> \frac 1\epsilon$" and you don't need to specify it.

Comment: I think the initial objection seems reasonable? It's just that this specific author has decided that N must be a positive integer for some reason. I found it a bit weird in the beginning because I didn't think it would matter. But, oh well.

Comment: tl;dr..... I think it would be fine to say "Let $N(\epsilon) > \frac 1{\epsilon}$ be a natural number".  Because the naturals are unbounded (I think it's fair to take *that* as a given) we don't have to actually waste any brain cells finding the cleanest and must efficient method of expressing the absolute least possible such $N$.

Comment: IMO, $N$ shouldn't have to an integer.  *BUT* the $n$ that is $\ge N$ must.  I think the author just wanted to avoid the issue.  It'd work exactly the same either way.

Comment: Yeap, as long as the reasoning I've given above make sense, I think I'm okay with it. I'll also note down what you have said for future reference when I begin studying Analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your proof seems to be good. (the answer practically ends here, but here is another way to prove it)

**Proof**. $$\frac {n^2+n+1} {(n+1)^2} = \frac {n^2+n+1} {n^2+2n+1}= 1 - \frac n {n^2+2n+1}$$.
We claim that $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac n {n^2+2n+1} = 0$$, and it can be shown that for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, as long as $n \gt N = \frac 1 {\epsilon}$, $$\lvert \frac n {n^2+2n+1} \rvert \lt \epsilon$$.  It is also true that $$\lim _{n\to+\infty} 1 = 1$$
Therefore $$\lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac {n^2+n+1} {(n+1)^2} = 1$$.